# Wordpress installation shows in plain html

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to install wordpress on a VPS. Created database, mysql user, unzipped wp file. All the usual.. works everywhere else, but on my new VPS it shows as plain HTML.

If I proceed, the installation is successful, but then the site can't function properly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcCZs.png

What could be the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Wrong urls ot can't access.

Comment: Make sure you can access all linked files, check the source. Alternatively check the "Network" interface from your browser console.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions! It turned out that simply chown of the main directory was needed to solve the problem.